# Can I license my code by providing a link to the license instead of the full text?

Tags: license-notice, license-file

As a person who wants to allow other people to use my code, I want to use a standard, proper license. But sometimes my code ends up being smaller than the LICENSE file that comes with it. This can especially annoying if I write a code snippet and want people to actually use it. I don't especially like the idea of copying and pasting 196 words of the MIT License, and then 30 words of the actual code itself. That just sounds absurdly wasteful.

Could I just mention that my code is under the MIT License (or any license for that matter) and then simply give a person the link to that license, so they can look at its terms and conditions?

Comment: If your code is *that* small, chances are it isn't even eligible for copyright protection.

Comment: It turns out that the Apache License has some [boilerplate legalese](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0#apply) that you can copy and paste in lieu of the license text. That's only 90 words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically it has to be very clear which license you use and the license text must be available. Usually it means that a file with the license text is put into the project and the files are marked that they use the license (a short comment like this: this is licensed under MIT License, see file LICENSE). Some tend to copying the full license text into each file of the project, which seems overkill.